# How can I refactor this long chain of similar promises

Tags: javascript, refactoring, cloudflare

How can I refactor the following code? For context, this is from cloudflare workers.

```
// Instantiate rewriter.
const rewriter = new HTMLRewriter()
.on('link', new AttributeHttpsRewriter('href'))
.on('img', new AttributeHttpsRewriter('src'))
.on('form', new AttributeHttpsRewriter('action'))
.on('script', new AttributeHttpsRewriter('src'))
.on('a', new AttributeHttpsRewriter('href'))
.on('iframe', new AttributeHostRewriter('src'))
.on('link', new AttributeHostRewriter('href'))
.on('link[rel="canonical"]', new AttributeHostRewriter('href'))
.on('link[rel="shortlink"]', new AttributeHostRewriter('href'))
.on('a', new AttributeHostRewriter('href'))
.on('meta', new AttributeHostRewriter('content'))
.on('form', new AttributeHostRewriter('action'))
.on('iframe', new AttributeHostRewriter('src'))
.on('textarea.clipboard-target',new TextHostRewriter());
```

I feel like it should be possible to have an object like:

```
{attributeRewriter: {'link':'href','img':'src','form':'action'} etc... }
```

And iterate through it. Is it as simple as calling

```
 rewriter.on(class,rewriter)
```

for each?

Is this even desirable?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this code is actually *not functional*. The purpose of the question was also to find out whether or not it is preferable to the original, and I think that it is not.

*Disregard:
It turns out my supposition was correct. I would like to know if you find this preferable to the original.

```
const rewriter = new HTMLRewriter();
const elemenetRewriters = [
 {
   type: AttributeHttpsRewriter,
   rewrites: {
     'link':'href',
     'img':'src',
     'form':'action',
     'script':'src',
     'a':'href',
   }
 },
 {
   type: AttributeHostRewriter,
   rewrites: {
     'link': 'href',
     'link[rel="canonical"]':'href',
     'link[rel="shortlink"]':'href',
     'a':'href',
     'meta':'content',
     'form':'action',
     'iframe':'src',
   }
 },
 {
   type: TextHostRewriter,
   rewrites: {
     'textarea.clipboard-target':null,
   }
 },
]

elementRewriters.forEach((elementRewriter)=>{
  for (const [tag, attribute] of Object.entries(elementRewriter)) {
    rewriter.on(tag,new elementRewriter.type(attribute));
  }
});
```

Comment: I think something like `'href': ['link', 'a', 'another']` would look more sorted then `'link': 'href', 'a': 'href', 'another': 'href'`. Btw your _refactor_ just went from 15 lines of code to 37. I would prefer the first one. As long as I don't know that library I am not sure, but I think these are not _promises_ but somekind of _handlers_. (Promises could use Promise.all()).

Comment: @Jax-p Pulling strings out is often suggested as a way to refactor, but I agree with you. I think in this case it makes it harder to read. Thanks for your thoughts.